# Footer tabs using NativeBase in iOS not working well

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, native-base

I'm using the component FooterTabs from NativeBase in my app, in Android all works well, but in iOS when I click another tab it displays the correct content but in the footer tabs is not changing the selected tab.

```
switchScreen(tabIndex) {
  this.setState({ tabIndex: tabIndex });
}

return(
  this.state.isLoading ?
  <Spinner color="black"/>
  :
  <Container>
      { tabContent }
    <Footer>
      <FooterTab>
        <Button active={ this.state.tabIndex == 0 ? true: false }
          onPress={ this.switchScreen.bind(this, 0) }>
          <Text>Descubrir</Text>
        </Button>
        <Button active={ this.state.tabIndex == 1 ? true: false }
          onPress={ this.switchScreen.bind(this, 1) }>
          <Text>Mi Galería</Text>
        </Button>
        <Button active={ this.state.tabIndex == 2 ? true: false }
          onPress={ this.switchScreen.bind(this, 2) }>
          <Text>Mis Cuadros</Text>
        </Button>
        <Button active={ this.state.tabIndex == 3 ? true: false }
          onPress={ this.switchScreen.bind(this, 3) }>
          <Text>Perfil</Text>
        </Button>
      </FooterTab>
    </Footer>
  </Container>
```

[image]

As you see I click my "Perfil Tab" and it shows me my Log Out button that is fine but "Mi galeria" tab is what is selected in the footer tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by reinstalling the native base dependency in my case:

- npm uninstall native-base
- npm install native-base@2.0.13
- react-native start --reset-cache
- react-native run-ios

Done!!

Comment: Good to know that you got it running